# Back button on product details page after search results

Tags: magento-1.7, product

I am using below code to show back button on product details page after search results but the back button doesn't show if I go the details page after search results. I am now checking using `$_product->getCategory()` but i need some condition to show back button after search result as well.

```
<?php if ($_category = $_product->getCategory()): ?>

<div class="back-button">
    <button onclick="history.back();" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Back') ?>" type="button">
        <span>
            <span><?php echo $this->__('Back') ?></span>
        </span>
    </button>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

I want to show back button on product details page when someone click product details page from search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `history.back()` there is no need to check if a product has a category. When coming from the search results the product has no category attached to it.
So you can remove the `if` statement. This way the button will behave just like pressing `back` in the browser. It will take you to the previous page no mater what. Even if you clicked on a related product or if you come from the cart page.
**EDIT**
Here is a way to get the page referrer

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER');
```

You can check if the referred contains the string `/catalogsearch/` and add it to your `if` statement.

Comment: if i removed all the condition then if anyone press directly the product details page link then also it shows back button.

Comment: I know... that's the down side. But in my opinion is a small risk

Comment: so can you give me some suggestion. My requirement is i want to show back button on product details page when someone click product details page from search results.

Comment: There is no way to determine from JS whether the user comes from the shop or not. But somewhere in magento (I can't find it) are the pages saved, the user visited in the past. You can just check there whether the user cames from a "local" link and if yes, show the back button. Then you only show it, if the user would not leave your page

Comment: @monojitbanik. I've edited my answer with a possible solution.

Comment: YES @MARIUS this is normal solution but thanks :) Actually i thought magento stores search result somewhere, because i have seen in many magento sites that prev/next button shows on product details page after clicking from search results.There must be a condition to show prev/next button.anyway thanks.